# Server to Server Websocket communication

Tags: python, websocket

Here is the architecture topology:

1. An IoT device that counts people and saves the data to its cloud platform. Data can be accessed via an API and more specific it requires to provide a webserver endpoint where it can push the data every minute or so. This a ready-made product that I cannot change the data transfer method.
2. A webserver on my side that receives and stores the data.

As I am new to WebSockets, I interpret the above configuration as a WebSocket server installed on my webserver and wait for the data to be received from the IoT server (client).

So I deployed a Linux server in digitalocean and enabled the websocket server to wait for the incoming connections. The code I used for the server is:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo(websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
                print(message)

start_server = websockets.serve(echo, "MYSERVERIP", 80)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

All I need at this stage is to print all JSON packets that are pushed from the IoT server.

When I try to set the endpoint address in the IoT server, it refuses to accept `ws://Myserver:80` and only accepts `HTTP://Myserver:80`. Obviously I don't have any HTTP server running on my server and therefore I am guessing the connection is refused from my server.

Also, the IoT API requires token X-Auth-token authentication. I am using the WebSockets python library but I didn't set up the authentication on my server. I left it null on both IoT server API and my server.
If I was to add a token authentication, what would be parameters or arguments required for the websocket server? I tried to search the websockets docs but with no luck.

This is not for production environment!! I am only trying to learn.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So these are the requirements:

1. An IoT device that counts people and saves the data to its cloud
   platform. Data can be accessed via an API and more specific it
   requires to provide a webserver endpoint where it can push the data
   every minute or so.
2. A webserver on my side that receives and stores
   the data.

They need data to be refresh every minute or so. In my humble opinion, websockets are neccesary only on real time.

That said, my proposed solution is to use a Message Broker instead. I think it's easier to handle than websockets directly, and you do not have to care about maintaining a live socket connection all the time (which is not efficient in terms of energy in IoT world).

In other words, use a **Pub/Sub** architecture instead. Your IoT devices **publish** data to the Message Broker (common one is RabbitMQ), and then you build a server that **subscribes** to the broker, consuming its data and stores it.

Now, every device connects to the cloud only when it has data available, this saves energy. The protocol may be MQTT or HTTP, MQTT is often used in the IoT world.

Related: [Pub-sub messaging benefits](https://aws.amazon.com/es/pub-sub-messaging/benefits/)

Comment: I totally agree with you regarding MQTT and Pub/Sub however I don't have the option to change the architecture of the IoT system. It only provides WebSocket communication for data transfer and therefore I have to build a WebSocket on my side. Thanks for your comment thought.